# Yii Site gets 404 error

Tags: yii2

I programmed an own yii-site called myScript_Formular.php,which has been put in
E:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject_Yii2.0\views\site. All other sites are in this folder,too!Furthermore,I added following code in SiteController:

```html
 public function actionScript() //A new method, programmed by Thomas Kipp
{
    $model = new myScriptForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        return $this->render('myScript', ['model' => $model]);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->render('myScript_Formular', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

If I try to get this page in yii2.0 in order to put in following url:

`http://localhost/MyProject_Yii2.0/web/index.php?r=site%2FmyScript_Formular`

I just get error:Not Found (#404)
What the hell is that? I controlled the name of the file thousands of times,it's correct and available in folder site.What should I do?

Comment: All the other sites run, but not my site!So, it's not a server error

Comment: Your action is named actionScript so you should call this action: site%2Fscript assuming the action resides inside the SiteController

Comment: you need to read guide first.  @Epiglottis has suggested correct way,

Comment: Helped! Thank you very,very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a little bit more precise I try to give you an official answer. The 404 error you got means that the url manager cannot resolve the url you provided to a route. The route in your case consists of a controller (site) and an action (script). You access your view through the action, therfore the url must form a valid route which identifies the controller and the action.

You should really read up on routing here: [Yii2 routing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#routing)